# Is it possible to print monochrome with System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo?

Tags: vb.net

I want to have two functions on my program but I can only print color. I also want to have an option "monochrome".

I have my code right here, can you tell me what I am missing?

```
Private Sub prntbtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles prntbtn.Click

        Dim psi As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
        
        Dim filepath = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        psi.UseShellExecute = True
        psi.Verb = "printto"
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        psi.FileName = filepath

        Dim myProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process
        myProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi)
        myProcess.WaitForInputIdle()

        Dim localProces As Diagnostics.Process = Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(myProcess.Id)
        localProces.CloseMainWindow()
        localProces.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is pushing responsibility off onto the default application for the file type to do the printing so it's out of your hands. It's up to that application how it does the printing.

Comment: can it be done through defaultPageSettings.Color = false ?

Comment: And what exactly would `defaultPageSettings` be in this context? If you want to do the printing yourself then you have full control, so you can do what you want. As I said though, you are deferring responsibility for the printing to the other application so that application would have to be the one to change any page settings.

Comment: what can I try to have it printed grayscale or monochrome?

Comment: Your application cannot tell another application how to print when started that way. It's simply not possible. You'd have to configure the other application, if it supported it. If you want control over printing then you need to do that printing yourself, using a `PrintDocument`. That's not going to be practical for complex documents.

Comment: BTW, based on what I've read, you should be using "print" rather than "printto". The latter is intended to support dragging and dropping of files on a printer icon. I think that it can be used in code but the idea is that you specify the printer that you want to print to. If it's working without specifying a printer for you then I guess it must be using the default printer.

Comment: Are you printing an arbitrary file or a specific file type(s)? If it's Office files, for instance, you can probably use Office Automation to actually control an instance of the appropriate Office application and that would give you control over the print process.

Comment: I'm using two options, PDF & WORD DOCUMENT.

Comment: If I use the PrintDocument, i think it refers to the form itself to print not the document I've chosen using OpenFileDialog

Comment: A `PrintDocument` doesn't "refer to the form". It raises it's `PrintPage` and then you write code to print whatever you want. As I said, that's not practical with for complex documents like PDF or DOC/X. For the Word documents, you could use Office Automation if you wanted to. Unless all your users will have a specific PDF reader installed that supports Automation though, I'd say that you're out of luck there.